# While loop not ending

Tags: python, windows, function, loops, while-loop

```
def getStocks():
    stockNames = []
    stockPrices = []
    done = 0
    while done != 1:
        stock = input('Enter Stock symbol: ')
        if stock == 'done':
            done = 1

        else:
            price = int(input('Enter Price of Stock: '))
            print("")
            stockNames.append(stock)
            stockPrices.append(price)
    return stockNames, stockPrices
```

The issue is that "Enter Stock symbol: " appears even after the user types 'done', how can I get the infinite loop to terminate at this point? I tried using break but it did not provide the results I was looking for

Comment: Are you inputting `'done'` or `done`? If you don't have the included quotation marks, it won't trigger the break condition.

Comment: Are you using python 2.7?

Comment: That is odd, I just ran it again and it seems to be okay. The issue was in my "main()" function in code that i did not provide. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `input` use `raw_input` it will fix the problem

```
def getStocks():
    stockNames = []
    stockPrices = []
    done = 0
    while done != 1:
        stock = raw_input('Enter Stock symbol: ')
        if stock == 'done':
            done = 1

        else:
            price = int(input('Enter Price of Stock: '))
            print("")
            stockNames.append(stock)
            stockPrices.append(price)
        return stockNames, stockPrices
```

python version:  2.7+

Answer (score 0):

you probably want `raw_input()`, as `input()` will actually try to evaluate the expression it gets back.